# convert a string number like "four" into '4' in mysql

Tags: mysql

In mysql database, I have a column named `runs` of varchar type in one table. Different rows consists of "FOUR","SIX","BYES",etc in runs column. Now I want to sum this `runs` column. so these ("FOUR","SIX",etc except "BYES") should convert into (4,6) of int data type.

Is there any function to make assume these string as integers and sum them to give a total. Please anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any limit? E.g. does "TWO THOUSAND THIRTEEN" qualify?

Comment: @ring0 It will still be most efficient to create a lookup table.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I swear I saw a PHP tag, sorry --

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski no worries. still not really constructive/ambiguous/vague

Comment: No, the question which i asked is not there, i am asking about ans in mysql. it was asked in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no function. You can create a "lookup" table that has the "word" version of the integer, and its integer value.

```
word   value
------------
one    1
two    2
three  3
four   4
five   5
...
```